# Stacked barplot with partitioned main and sub x label

Tags: r, stack, bar-chart

I'm new to R. I want to create a stacked barplot based on the following data. I want to plot these data into a stacked barplot that describes percentage of disease score for each combination of genotype and race in x axis, e.g. 76R-race 1, rmc-race 1. As well how to simplify the x axis, by splitting each race to have 76R and rmc combination instead of labelling each combination, i.e. instead of labelling each bar with 76R-race 1, rmc-race 1, etc, how to label race 1 as main axis and have 76R and rmc as sub-axis, and so on.

```
disease.nov <- data.frame(disease.score = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 8, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 7, 4, 7, 7, 8, 6, 8, 8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 4, 9, 9, 5, 3, 8, 8, 6, 5, 7, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 8, 4, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                      genotype=gl(2,52,624, labels=c("76R","rmc")),     
                      race=gl(6,104,624, labels=c("race 1","race 2","race 3","WAC 7673","WAC 7591","control")))
```

Comment: It'll serve you better if you make an attempt yourself. I found the following online resource very useful to gain familiarity with plotting in R: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

Comment: I'm going to second what @MattWeller said - the `ggplot2` package is something you should learn if you want to make charts in R. I absolutely love it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(disease.nov, aes(x=genotype, fill=factor(disease.score))) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill") + 
  facet_wrap(~ race) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: @CahyaPrihatna if this answers your question, please accept the solution.